# React-Router same-page anchors with browserHistory

Tags: anchor, react-router

Using `React-Router` with `browserHistory`, how can I create a same-page link to an item on the page?

In one component:

```
<Link to='/coolRoute#coolThing'>Cool Thing</Link>
```

In another:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div id='coolThing'></div>
  );
}
```

When I click the link the browser URL changes properly, but nothing actually happens (I would expect a scroll up/down the page to the element.

I know that the id is present on the page because doing `document.getElementById('coolThing')` works just fine.